# trunc(sysdate) PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, truncate

In Oracle, if you use

```
select trunc(SYSDATE) from dual;
```

We get the current date, but in PostgreSQL will it work?

Is there even a similar design in Postgre?

Comment: Select current_date;

Comment: [Current date/time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle's DATE data type (which is what `sysdate` returns) always contains a time part which can not be removed. `trunc()` will set that to `00:00:00`

If you want a date/time value (=timestamp) where the time part is `00:00:00` then you can use `current_date::timestamp` or `date_trunc('day', current_timestamp)`. Note that the latter returns a `timestamp with time zone`, not a `timestamp` value

However, Postgres' `date` type does not contain a time part (it's a "real" date). If you want that, use `current_date`. As it does not contain a time (by definition) there is no need for a "trunc" or something similar.